# Routing in Codeigniter. Regexp needed. Find everything that does not contains a specific word

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes, regex-lookarounds

I have some troubles with routing in Codeigniter framework. I'm in desperate need of finding regexp that will recognise string in URL when there is no ***'admin'*** included

**Information about enviroment:**

- Codeigniter Framework
- i18n Multi language Library Helper (Language is changed when en/ ru/ fr/ is added to URL)
- HMVC modules enabled with **main** and **admin** modules

**Routing options:**

```
1. $route['default_controller'] = "main";
2. $route['(\w{2})?\/admin\/?(.*)'] = 'admin/$2';
3. $route['(\w{2})?\/?((?!admin).*)'] = 'main/$2';
4. $route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
5. $route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Describing the problem with routing  behaviour.**

- I want to access admin module by adding "admin" to URL address (**this works fine**)
- I want to access admin with language indicator like "en/admin" (**this works also fine**)
- I want to access "main" module without writing "main" in URL address. Instead of http://somewebsite.com/main/controller/method I would like to use http://somewebsite.com/controller/method

**Summary**

In my routing configuration I need regexp which will launch "**main**" module when there is no "**admin**" word in URL address. This should also work with internalization.

I've alredy came up with `(\w{2})?\/((?!admin).*)` but it works only when I add language to URL like "somewebsite.com/*en*/some_controller/(...)" because "/" is recognised.

I also tried `(\w{2})?\/((?!admin).*)|((?!admin).*)` but there is third group added so the  "**main/$2**" rule will not work ("main/$3" should do the trick but it doesn't)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of the url you want to match with `main` and the url you don't want to match with `admin`?

Comment: let's say I have "User" controller and "Show" method in "Main" module. The url should be http://somewebsite.com/user/show. This also dont match with admin. To access Admin functionallity I should write http://somewebsite.com/admin/controller/method -> this match "admin" so "Admin" module is activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following settings for **Routing** file works for me. Please note the order of the rules

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['admin'] = 'admin';
$route['(\w{2}\/)?admin\/?'] = 'admin';
$route['(\w{2}\/)?admin\/?(.*)'] = 'admin/$2';
$route['(\w{2}\/)?((?!admin).*)'] = 'main/$2';
$route['(\w{2})?/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```